# How to prevent TeamCity from storing build artifacts?

Tags: teamcity

TeamCity automatically stores files it believes are build artifacts. All of our artifacts are stored in Octopus Deploy, so this is unnecessary.

How do you configure TeamCity not to store build artifacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TeamCity doesn't store build artifacts by default.**

Confirmed by Julia Reshetnikova in a [support ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-56364):

What's happening is that a build step is pushing the artifacts using service messages. Configure the build steps to not push artifacts.

If the build steps do not allow configuring this, then the best thing you can do is configure a clean-up rule to remove build artifacts as fast as possible.

1. Go to the  settings
2. Click on Clean-up Rules in the left navigation.
3. You may see multiple "build configuration or template", for each:
4. Click Edit.
5. Under "Clean Artifacts", choose custom policy.
6. Choose 1 days since last build or "1th" successful build, whichever makes the most sense to you.

All subprojects under  will inherit this configuration. After this is configured, you can force TeamCity to run a cleanup by:

1. Go to the Administration page
2. Choose Clean-up Settings in the left navigation
3. Click "Start clean-up now"

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to save artifacts, just remove **Artifact paths** from all projects

One more suggestion. Open Global Settings, sets **Maximum build artifact file size** to **0 Kb**

Also, you can clean all the collected data

go to **Administration** > **Server Administration** >  **Clean-up Settings**

The **Previous clean-up**  section of the server clean-up settings enables you to:

- review the information on the previous server clean-up date and duration helping you decide whether to launch the clean-up process at a given moment
- run clean-up manually using the **Start clean-up now**  button

During clean-up, TeamCity reports the progress. If you need, you can stop the clean-up process and the remaining data will be removed during the next clean-up.

Just press the button **Start clean-up now**

[image]

Comment: So what you're saying is that TeamCity does not have a first-class way of disabling storing artifacts.

Comment: Unfortunately, these suggestions aren't working. All projects do not have artifact paths set. Setting the maximum build artifact file size now causes all builds to fail: "Failed to publish artifacts: Artifact file has size 464806353 bytes which exceeds maximum allowed size of 0 bytes""

Comment: Clean-up does not remove the artifacts.

Comment: clean-up should remove. what error you had when cleaning?

Comment: There's no error. It just doesn't remove them. There's 50GB of artifacts and there continues to be after successful execution.